# How to make a List<> from 2 list of object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have object CartItem and Product.
I need to make one List<> from these 2 objects.

Tried:
`List<(CartItem,Product)> product = new List<(CartItem,Product)>();`

Code:

```
      public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var username = User.Identity.Name;

            if (username == null)
            {
                return Login();
            }
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == username);
            List<CartItem> cart = _context.ShoppingCartItems.Where(s => s.IDuser.Equals(user.Id)).ToList();
            List<Product> product = new List<Product>();


            foreach (var item in cart)
            {
                product.Add(_context.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.ProductId));
            }
            

            return View(user);
        }
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Are the types `Product` and `CartItem` related in any way?

Comment: What does `I need to make one List<> from these 2 objects.` mean? All generic containers can hold items of a single type only. While you *can* create a list of tuples, what would you put in there if you have eg 2 products and 5 items? All combinations? 5 tuples with 3 null products?

Comment: Use [Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-7.0), but if you are loading from the db you should probably do the join in the DB instead.

Comment: Besides, your code is loading both CartItem and Product objects from the database using loops. If `CartItem` has  `Product` and `User` properties as it should you can remove *all* of this code and replace it with `var cart=_context.ShoppingCartItems.Include(i=>i.Product).Where(s=>s.User.email==userName).ToList();` EF Core will generate the SQL query that joins User, CartItem, Product together and returns items *and* their products

Comment: @JonasH you can't join collections of different types. Besides, all this code is trying to load related items from the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What gave you that idea? The signature is `Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>`, there is nothing that requires that TOuter and TInner to be the same type?

Comment: @JonasH oops, I got confused with Union. It's still not helpful though for several reasons. First, that performs on the client the JOIN that should be done by EF Core. Second, Join will do what `item.Product=product` would do if `CartItem had such a property. Or, if the OP insists on tuples, instead of `List<Product>` they could use a `List<(CartItem,Product)>` and add items inside the loop. All of this can be replaced with a single call though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Completely agree that it *should* be done in the database. But it *could* still be done on the client: `products.Join(carts, p => p.Id, c => c.ProductId, (c, p) => (c, p));` should work.

Comment: @JonasH that would make sense if the loop was replaced with `_context.Product.Where(x => cartProductIds.Contains(x.id)).ToList()` to replace the N queries with a single one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer would be to *not* do that. What would be the expected result for 5 items and 2 products?

The code is loading both CartItem and Product objects from the database using loops. That's very slow as each object requires yet another query. This can be replaced with a single line producing a single SQL query.

If `CartItem` has  `Product` and `User` properties (as it should) all the code can be replaced with :

```
var cart=_context.ShoppingCartItems
                 .Include(i=>i.Product)
                 .Where(s=>s.User.Email==userName)
                 .ToList();
```

EF Core will generate the SQL query that joins User, CartItem, Product together and returns items *and* their products, but no `User` data. The `Product` data will be available through the `CartItem.Product` property

**What was asked but shouldn't be used**

If a `List<(CartItem,Product)>` is absolutely required (why???) you could use that instead of a `List<Product>`, and add items inside the loop:

```
// PLEASE don't do it this way
var dontUseThis = new List<(CartItem,Product?)>();
foreach (var item in cart)
{
    var product=_context.Product.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.ProductId);
    dontUseThis.Add((item,product));
}
```

This will result in one extra SQL query per cart item.

**Slightly better**

A slightly better option would be to generate a `WHERE product.ID IN (....)` clause, to load all relevant products in a single query. After that the two lists would have to be joined with JOIN.

```
var productIds=cart.Select(c=>c.ProductId);

var products=_context.Product
                     .Where(p=>productIds.Contains(p.Id))
                     .ToList();

var dontUseThis = products.Join(cart, 
                                p => p.Id, 
                                c => c.ProductId, 
                                (c, p) => (c,p))
                          .ToList();
```

This will reduce the N+1 queries to 2. It's still slower than letting the database do the work though

Answer (score 1):

First, see the answer of @Panagiotis Kanavos. Aside that, for combining part, you can do this:

```
List<CartItem> cartItems; // assuming you already have this
List<Product> products; // assuming you already have this

// The combination part
var result = from p in products
             join ci in cartItems on p.Id = ci.ProductId // Find out how product and cartItem relates
             select new (p,ci);

// Need List?
var resultingList = result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a struct and put both variables in there:

```
struct EntireProduct
{
    CartItem cartItem;
    Product product;
}
```

then you can create a list of that struct:

```
List<EntireProduct> product = new List<EntireProduct>();
```